# Illegal string offset with float and int strings

Tags: php, string, foreach

I need to show on page some data from json_decode, but I receive an illegal offset error.

```
$json = '{"result":{"keyword":"seo",
                    "cost":0.54,
                    "concurrency":25,
                    "found_results":422000000,
                    "region_queries_count":1900,
                    "region_queries_count_wide":0,
                    "region_queries_count_phrase":0,
                    "types":["related_search","pic"],
                    "geo_names":[],
                    "social_domains":["wikipedia","linkedin"],
                    "right_spelling":null,
                    "keyword_length":1,
                    "lang":null,
                    "keyword_id":"647713",
                    "suggestions_count":12528,
                    "keywords_count":1637
                    },
          "status_msg":"OK",
          "status_code":200,
          "left_lines":99787
         }';
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
if (is_array($obj['result'])) {
foreach ($obj['result'] as $keywords) {

echo '<li>Keyword: "'.$keywords['keyword'].'", Adwords CPC: <b>'.$keywords['cost'].'</b> USD, Concurrency: <b>'.$keywords['concurrency'].'</b>, Results: <b>'.$keywords['found_results'].'</b>, Search Volume: <b>'.$keywords['region_queries_count'].'</b>.</li>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '</ol>';
 }
}    

var_dump($obj) return:
array(4) { ["result"]=> array(16) { ["keyword"]=> string(3) "seo" ["cost"]=> float(0.54) ["concurrency"]=> int(25) ["found_results"]=> int(422000000) ["region_queries_count"]=> int(1900) ["region_queries_count_wide"]=> int(0) ["region_queries_count_phrase"]=> int(0) ["types"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "related_search" [1]=> string(3) "pic" } ["geo_names"]=> array(0) { } ["social_domains"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "wikipedia" [1]=> string(8) "linkedin" } ["right_spelling"]=> NULL ["keyword_length"]=> int(1) ["lang"]=> NULL ["keyword_id"]=> string(6) "647713" ["suggestions_count"]=> int(12528) ["keywords_count"]=> int(1637) } ["status_msg"]=> string(2) "OK" ["status_code"]=> int(200) ["left_lines"]=> int(99791) }
```

Comment: `foreach ($obj as $keywords) {`

Comment: which line you get the error

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset  - this is on echo line.

Comment: Changing foreach ($obj['result'] as $keywords) to {foreach ($obj as $keywords) works and show the data, but error is again present on page.

Comment: Can your result set contain more than 1 keyword data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating through the `$obj['results']` array, but that is already the root element you want for your keywords. Just use this instead:

```
$keywords = $obj['result'];
echo '<li>Keyword: "'.$keywords['keyword'].'", Adwords CPC: <b>'.$keywords['cost'].'</b> USD, Concurrency: <b>'.$keywords['concurrency'].'</b>, Results: <b>'.$keywords['found_results'].'</b>, Search Volume: <b>'.$keywords['region_queries_count'].'</b>.</li>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '</ol>';
```

Output:

```
<li>Keyword: "seo", Adwords CPC: <b>0.54</b> USD, Concurrency: <b>25</b>, Results: <b>422000000</b>, Search Volume: <b>1900</b>.</li> </ol>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2j5Cg)

Comment: @EduardDimitrov in that JSON there is only one result set... Can you give an example of a JSON where there is more than one result set?

Answer (score 2):

If there is the possibility of having multiple keywords, then this could be presented as an array of objects.  Whereas a single keyword is presented by a standalone JSON object.  To cope with both of these, this code will check if it is an array of objects, if it isn't then it converts the single entry into an array so that both options can be processed using the same code...

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
if (isset($obj['result'])) {
    // If not a numerically indexed array - convert it
    if ( !isset($obj['result'][0]))  {
        $obj['result'] = [$obj['result']];
    }
    foreach ($obj['result'] as $keywords) {
        echo '<li>Keyword: "'.$keywords['keyword'].'", Adwords CPC: <b>'.$keywords['cost'].'</b> USD, Concurrency: <b>'.$keywords['concurrency'].'</b>, Results: <b>'.$keywords['found_results'].'</b>, Search Volume: <b>'.$keywords['region_queries_count'].'</b>.</li>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '</ol>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I did ask for an example of a JSON with multiple results in it... this is probably how it should be done. But based on the API URL I'm not sure that it is designed to return more than one result at once,

Comment: @Nick, yes, its not designed to return more than one results at once, this is the reason I work over this tool. Anyway, both solutions works great. Thank you very match to all!